# KVO infinit loop with 2 way binding

Tags: ios, swift, binding, key-value-observing

I have two classes. Class `A` has Class `B`, but class `B` does not know of the existence of class `A`

Both classes can be altered by external factors (such as services or logic)

But I need to keep both classes synchronized with the same value

As class `A` knows of class `B`, I can do a direct assignment after its value is changed

To make the class `B` know the Class `A`, I decided to implement KVO, in this way class `A` is notified when class `B` is changed

My code looks something like this

```
class A : NSObject {
    var b : B

    @objc dynamic var anOtherString:String? {
        didSet{
            b.someString = self.anOtherString
        }
    }

    override init() {
        self.b = B()
        super.init()
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(b.someString), options: [.old , .new], context: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Key-Value Observing
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        if keyPath == #keyPath(b.someString) {
            // Update Time Label
            anOtherString = b.someString
        }
    }

}


class B : NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var someString: String?
}
```

The problem is that my code stays in infinite loop

Because whenever my class `B` is changed it notifies class `A`, and when class `A` is updated it changes again the value of class `B` that creates a new notification and so on...

I already tried to analyze the `Thread.callStackSymbols` to detect the cycle and stop it but without success.

Comment: Does your real code do more? For the code you posted there is no reason why class A has to observe class B. All you do in class A when `b.someString` is changed is to then update `b.someString` with the same value. There's no reason for any of that.

Comment: Of course you could add a check if the old and new values are the same. If they are the same, don't do anything.

Comment: @maddy - I thought to check the old and new values. But this is in a very complex application and in specific cases does not work, and it is necessary to create alternative solutions for these cases

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot allow A to update B when A was changed due to B, you could have a boolean variable that tracks if A needs to update B.

```
class A : NSObject {
    var b : B
    var bChanged: Bool = false // Logic to track if B made a change

    @objc dynamic var anOtherString:String? {
        didSet{
            // If B did not make a change, then update B
            if !bChanged {
                b.someString = self.anOtherString

            // Otherwise set the flag
            }else {
                bChanged = false
            }
        }
    }

    override init() {
        self.b = B()
        super.init()
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(b.someString), options: [.old , .new], context: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Key-Value Observing
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        if keyPath == #keyPath(b.someString) {
            // Update Time Label
            bChanged = true // B made a change
            anOtherString = b.someString
        }
    }
}
```